C# application only returning half the error on IIS
I have a C# application that when I run it through VS 2012 on my local machine it returns the whole error message.
.
When I deploy to IIS it only returns half the message.

main.aspx
<script language="javascript">
function save_button(Connection,ProcName,ProcInstance,NoParam )
{           
    var params = new Array(NoParam.value) ;

    params[0]=eZ1;
    ...
    params[22]=Inp_1_25.value;      

    run_ora_proc(Connection.value, ProcName.value, ProcInstance.value, NoParam.value,params);
}
</script>

generic.js
function run_ora_proc(Connection,ProcName,ProcInstance,NoParam,Params)
{
    window.status = "Executing stored procedure "+ProcName+" ...";
    startHourglass();
    call_ajax('ClientRunStoredProc', Params, Connection, ProcName, ProcInstance, NoParam);
}

function call_ajax(Method, params,Connection,ProcName,ProcInstance,NoParam)
{
    var PAGE_SUCCESS = 200;
    var requestObject;
    var ComponentId = "";
    var ComponentHTML = "";
    var ErrCode = 0;

    var url = new String("ajax.aspx");
    var param = "Method=" + Method; 
    switch(Method)
    {
        ...     
        case "ClientRunStoredProc":
            param = param + "&ConName=" + Connection;
            param = param + "&ProcName=" + ProcName;
            param = param + "&ProcInstance=" + ProcInstance;
            param = param + "&NoParam=" + NoParam;
            for (var i=1;i<=parseInt(NoParam);i++)
            {
                param = param + "&par" + i + "=" + ReplaceAmpURL(ReplaceHashURL(ReplacePlusURL(params[i-1])));
            }
            break;
            
        ...
        default:
            break;
    }
    

    requestObject = xmlHttpRequestHandler.createXmlHttpRequest();
    requestObject.open("Post",url,true);

    // Required if using the POST method - also send value pairs in the send method else null for GET method
    requestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    requestObject.send(param);
    requestObject.onload = function() {
    if(requestObject.status==PAGE_SUCCESS)
    { 
        try
        {
            var retStr = new String(requestObject.responseText); 
            retStr = retStr.split("@");
            ComponentId = retStr[0]
            ComponentHTML = retStr[1];
            switch(Method)
            {
                case "ClientRunStoredProc":
                    stopHourglass();
                    if (retStr[0] == '30000')
                    {
                        window.alert(retStr[1]);    // display just the message as it is a user message
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (retStr[0] == '50000')
                        {
                            page_populate(retStr[1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (retStr[0] != '0' && retStr[0] != '')
                            {
                                window.alert('Error No : '+retStr[0]+ '\n'+'Error Msg : '+retStr[1]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //window.alert('Procedure completed successfully !!');
                                page_refresh();     // Each page perform diff actions after SP call. Handled in d03_pagedetail.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    window.status = "Done";
                    break;
        
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (x)
        {
        }
    } 
    else
        { 
            ErrCode = requestObject.status;
            switch(Method)
            {
                ...
                case "ClientRunStoredProc":
                    window.alert("Error running Oracle Stored Procedure "+ProcName+" ...\n\nXMLHttpRequest Status : "+requestObject.status);
                    break;
                ...
            } 
        } 
    }
    window.status = "Done";
    stopHourglass();
    return ErrCode;
}


The ajax call, calls an Oracle 11g stored procedure which return the message. Both my local machine and the IIS server are connecting to the same Oracle database.
Update
This application used to work correctly on our old IIS server. It has since been scrapped so I'm not sure what it's spces were.
Is there a setting or something that I can change to fix this?
Local Machine.
64 bit Windows 10 Enterprise.
IIS server
64 bit Windows server 2016 standard
IIS version 10.0.14393.0
Visual Studio
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated)
Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084
Installed Version: IDE Standard
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012   04932-004-0017006-02235
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012
Visual Basic 2012   04932-004-0017006-02235
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012
Visual C# 2012   04932-004-0017006-02235
Microsoft Visual C# 2012
Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio   11.2.0.3.20
Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2012
SQL Server Analysis Services
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer
Version 11.0.3436.0
SQL Server Integration Services
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 11.0.3436.0
SQL Server Reporting Services
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 11.0.3436.0

We need to see the code that sets the "User Message" - its not an error/exception and its a string most likely in config. It's highly unlikely it'll be a Message.Substring(0, aVar); what's more likely is a RESX or PO file with Strings. In one environment someone has accidentally deleted part of the string.

@JeremyThompson I'm the only developer working on this project so I know that the code is exactly the same. window.alert('Error No : '+res.value[0]+ '\n'+'Error Msg : '+res.value[1]); . The res variable is not edited after it is returned from the DB.

[Edit] your question to include the code and also the endpoint code that's returning the data to the Javascript FrontEnd.

This should be a code issue, can you share the relevant code? Or you can open a support ticket for this, microsoft engineers will help find the root cause.

There are several issues with this purely Javascript code. The "error" code runs on success and displays the second item of the array returned by retStr.split("@") which can have more than just 2 items.  Second, HTTP requests are made with the fetch Javascript method, not XmlHttpRequestHandler. That object was only needed in the early 2000s, before jQuery and before all browsers got the native fetch command.

This application was was developed in the early 2000s and worked fine until we had to move it to a new server and database. I can't remember the specs of the old server but I know it was a 42 bit machine.
